# Why are the Boots of Striding and Springing based on longstrider?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

[The Boots of Striding and Springing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-striding-and-springing/) are a very common/popular item for players to buy. When looking at its construction requirements we see that its based off of the spell longstrider, which makes little sense as [longstrider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/longstrider/) is a druid/ranger spell, two classes that are rare item crafters. Generally magic items are based off of sorcerer/wizard and cleric spell lists as they tend to be the creators of magic items. There does exist an spell for wizards which resembles longstrider called [Expeditious Retreat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/expeditious-retreat/) which is just faster but shorter duration.

Since there are items which have different pricing that doesnt follow the magic item crafting rules for their abilities or that differ from the spell used, why wouldnt they have just used the more likely spell and make that change?

Comment: Maybe edit the question to ask for designer commentary or similar; otherwise, answers will be pure speculation.

Comment: Remember that "Why do you think the designers made choice *X*?" is not a type of question RPG.se accepts. For discussion-style questions like that, you probably want a [discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321).

Answer (score 1):

Because the item's price would be considerably different.

Longstrider lasts for 1 hour/level, while expeditious retreat lasts 1 minute/level. According to the table, a magic item that uses the effect of a spell with minutes/level duration has **double the base price**.

The item's price is 5,500 gp. If we break it down, we got 2,000 for a constant first level spell, and 2,500 for a +5 skill bonus (even if limited). The lowest priced effect has the price increased by 50%, for a total of 2,500+3,000, or 5,500 gp.

If the spell effect used was expeditious retreat, the breakdown would be 4,000 for the spell effect and 2,500 for the skill bonus, which would increase by 50% to 3,750. The final price would be 7,750.

Answer (score -1):

### Multiclassing. But chicken or the egg?

Either a wizard/ranger(or druid) multiclass character realized his multiclasses didn't work well for adventuring and decided he may as well put his skill to use in the boots business, or a wizard saw the popularity of this sort of boot and picked up some sweet sweet Ranger multiclass for this great opportunity.

There are people out there who just want to settle down and make a living.